# Poweshell Start-Job from serviceAccount using SailPoint IQService

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

So there are several factors in play with this question, so here they are:

- SailPoint 8.2 and IQService 8.2
- Windows Server 2016
- A service Account(Domain Admin)
- An interactive User account (Domain admin)
- Powershell 5.1 build 14393 revision 4583

So what we have is SailPoint is executing a rule on its end, sending over some information to IQService, and IQService is executing the PowerShell scripts as the service account. In one of the PowerShell scripts, we have the following command:

```
LogToFile("calling start job")


$j = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { C:/SailPoint/Scripts/PowershellContainerAfterCreateRetry.ps1 -sAMAccountName $args[0] -company $args[1] } -ArgumentList $sAMAccountName, $company -Name 'PowershellContainerAfterCreateRetry'
LogToFile($j | Select-Object -Property *)
LogToFile("finished start-job")
```

and this is where things get interesting because this command, as you can note, we can log to file to see what its output is, which is as follows:

```
calling start job
@{
State=Running; HasMoreData=True; 
StatusMessage=; 
Location=localhost; 
Command= C:/SailPoint/Scripts/PowershellContainerAfterCreateRetry.ps1 -sAMAccountName $args[0] -company $args[1] ; 
JobStateInfo=Running;
Finished=System.Threading.ManualResetEvent; 
InstanceId=aa889c06-7a8a-402e-807a-880d02465bdd; Id=1; 
Name=PowershellContainerAfterCreateRetry; 
ChildJobs=System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Management.Automation.Job]; 
PSBeginTime=10/15/2021 21:14:22; PSEndTime=; 
PSJobTypeName=BackgroundJob;
Output=System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection`1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject];
Error=System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection`1[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord];
Progress=System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection`1[System.Management.Automation.ProgressRecord];
Verbose=System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection`1[System.Management.Automation.VerboseRecord];
Debug=System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection`1[System.Management.Automation.DebugRecord];
Warning=System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection`1[System.Management.Automation.WarningRecord];
Information=System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection`1[System.Management.Automation.InformationRecord]}
finished start-job
```

When I execute this command either by itself OR within this script using Windows PowerShell ISE, it completes with no issue and calls the script in question, and everything works perfectly! (whether I am using my interactive account OR the service account)

When this script executes using the IQService, something "else" is happening - I say something "else" because I don't have any log files or errors; it just seems to disappear into the ether. (I have a log write out five lines into the PowerShell script, so one would think I would at least get SOMETHING!?!? I am out of ideas...thoughts?

As a minor note, I ran an experiment that showed me that there is something strange about the setup which should have succeeded without issue - like the above it appears to execute (because I can see the same information above, that shows that the job has started). Still, just like the above, it never actually "appears" to complete or error out. The only thing I can think of is that somehow the primary script closing out is causing this to close out as well - but I would think it would be able to get a couple of log files written to if that was the case? Anyway...thanks for reading!

```
$doit = {
"test" | Out-File -filepath ("c:\test.txt") -append
}
Start-job -ScriptBlock $doit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think Start-Job is the problem here, as iqservice will launch a powershell script process and that may not support the background job aspect you are trying to use.

if you need to have something retry or wait and loop, you'll need to use another identityiq/iqservice mechanism (a workflow in iiq perhaps that calls down to AD when conditions are, timer is hit, etc.) beyond start-job inside of an iqservice powershell script.